# In C, how to release global static pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, static, free

In C, please look over this codes,

```
static char* test = NULL;
typedef struct
{
    char* member1;
}TestStruct;


void testCode()
{
    TestStruct ts;
    test = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    //assign characters to each test 0 ~ 9 positions 
    ts.member1 = test;
    // using ts, then can I free static pointer test using free()?
    free(test);
}
```

1) Is this free code right?
2) Allocated memory test pointing is in heap, right?
3) test is in .bss?
4) if testCode() function can be called in thread, test is one, right? but every time thread calls testCode(), test will be assigned with new pointer and makes memory leak, right? So, can I use this code to avoid it?

```
 Mutex_Start
 if(test == NULL)
     test = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
 Mutex_End
```

Please help me.

Comment: Show more code (by editing your question), and tell what your operating system is. Threads and mutexes are OS specific (e.g. different on Linux & on Windows).

Comment: Do you want the threads to operate on the same memory?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Not since C11 :)

Comment: Agreed, but C11 is so recent that few compilers support it...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's why we'll have to keep nagging about C11, until they finally implement it! :)

Comment: @Lindin: you could contribute efforts to GCC to help them implement C11.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this free code right?

If the intent is to allocate 10 bytes of memory, then assign a pointer to point at that memory, then delete the memory, then it is correct.

But the comment in the code suggests that you are a bit confused. `ts.member1 = test;` will only make another pointer point at the same chunk of data. You have not made a hard copy of anything. From the moment when you `free(test)`, then both `test` and `ts.member1` are pointing at invalid memory.

> Allocated memory test pointing is in heap, right?

Yes.

> test is in .bss?

Yes.

> if testCode() function can be called in thread, test is one, right?

Every time the function is called, a new chunk of memory will be created. But the same function also `free()` the memory. Of course, if another thread gets focus before the first one reaches `free()`, it will allocate yet another chunk of memory. Example:

- Thread 1: malloc memory at address 1234
- Test is pointing at 1234
- Context switch
- Thread 2: malloc memory at address 5678
- Test is pointing at 5678
- Nothing is pointing at 1234 any longer - memory leak
- Thread 2: free memory at address 5678. NOTE: free() does not set the pointer to NULL.
- Thread 2: done
- Thread 1: free memory at address 5678 (test is still pointing there)
- Thread 1: crash & burn

So you have a memory leak and a runtime crash both.

> So, can I use this code to avoid it?

The check against NULL prevents the second thread from allocating any new memory. If that is the intention and both threads are supposed to access the same memory, then it will prevent against the above mentioned bug. But the actual memory will have to be protected against race conditions as well, the code gets complex. The proper way to do this is likely to allocate everything locally, rather than through a file scope pointer.

Comment: He is checking whether test==NULL before allocating memory, so if it is assigned it won't allocated it again, is not it ?

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you missing is

```
test = NULL;
```

after

```
free(test);
```

And make same protection on the free, as you do before mallocing

Comment: That solves nothing, because you could still get a context switch between `free(test)` and `test = NULL`. You would have to protect the access to `test` with a mutex.

Comment: @Lundin This is what i meant when i suggested to make similar protection on freeing, to put mutex. Anyway i don't see much sense to handle this memory global, unless it is something immutable, but then it should be allocated in init stage, and freed on finalization.

Answer (score 1):

You can always do the call to `free` after all your threads have finished namely in a function that you register with `atexit` to be run at the end of your process. But this is really of minor concern, since the process will free all allocated memory at the end, anyhow.

More important is the startup. Modern C, AKA C11, has threads and mutexes, so you could use that, but it also has another construct that would be more appropriate, here, atomics.

```
static char*_Atomic test = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);


void testCode(void)
{
    TestStruct ts;
    while (!test) {
      char* tmp = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
      if (!atomic_compare_exchange(&test, tmp, 0))
        free(tmp);
    }
   /* Do whatever you have to do, here */
   ...
}
```

If your platform doesn't support this aspect of C11, yet, you can emulate it on many platforms by means of [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr).

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple threads to work on the same memory you should probably put the malloc and free into the code that starts and joins the threads. You could also do some kind of reference counting:

```
static char* test = NULL;
static int refCount = 0;

void testCode()
{
    TestStruct ts;

    {
        //mutex lock;
        if (!refCount++)
            test = malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    }

    //assign characters to each test 0 ~ 9 positions 
    ts.member1 = test;

    {
        //mutex lock;
        if (!--refCount)
            free(test);
    }
}
```

If the global pointer is some kind of global ressource and the threads don't have to work on it in parallel, you should put a mutex around the *entire* function from malloc to free. If you only protect malloc and free seperately, one thread could free the memory that another thread is working on!